# LINQ Join through 3 tables to Sum one column

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I'm trying to get the total number of sales per City and display the result in a DataGrid. So far I've lost more hair than made progress. I'm new to LINQ and I'm probably stressing over nothing. Here's what I've got:

```
var sales = from sale in db.SalesOrderHeaders
                    join cust in db.Customers on sale.CustomerID equals cust.CustomerID
                    join cad in db.CustomerAddresses on cust.CustomerID equals cad.CustomerID
                    join ad in db.Addresses on cad.AddressID equals ad.AddressID
                    group sale.TotalDue by ad.City into g
                    select new { City = ad.City, Sales = g.Sum() };
```

And here's the dbml. Its the TotalDue Column I'm tryin to sum and sort by City in the Address Table.
[image]

Would Appreciate any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `City = g.Key` instead of `City = ad.City`

But you most likely do not need to use the `join` syntax at all, since you have already set up the relationships in your database. You can just use the navigation properties on the objects

```
var sales = from ad in db.Addresses
            from cad in ad.CustomerAddresses
            from sale in cad.Customer.SalesOrderHeaders
            group sale.TotalDue by ad.City into g
            select new
            {
                City = g.Key, 
                Sales = g.Sum()
            };
```

I assumed you want to group by the`CustomerAddress`, maybe you want to use the `ShipToAddress` or `BillToAddress`?

Comment: I tried using the syntax you supplied but it raised an error Error 1 'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet<WpfApplication1.CustomerAddress>' does not contain a definition for 'Address' and no extension method 'Address' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet<WpfApplication1.CustomerAddress>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What properties exist for `CustomerAddress`? On second look, I think the problem is occurring because 1 `Customer` can have many `Addresses`. So your group by city should probably occur using the `BillToAddress` on the `SalesOrderHeader`?

Comment: I think your right. Customers can have a Shipping address of MainOffice Address. Ill trying grouping by the Shipping Address.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the joins, because you can use navigation properties, and you can start the query at the other end:

```
from address in db.Address
select new 
       {
           City = address.City,
           Sales = (from ca in address.CustomerAddresses
                    // where ca.AddressType == someVariable  
                    from soh in ca.Customer.SalesOrderHeaders
                    select soh.TotalDue).Sum()
       }
```

The navigation properties don't show in the dbml diagram, but they are there in the c# classes.

You can add the where clause (`where ca.AddressType == someVariable`) if you want the sum for a specific address type.

Comment: This does the whole operation in one query. With LINQ-to-SQL, `group by` fires a separate query for each group in the result (n + 1 anti pattern).